# jquery inline editor behaviour

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code to try and build a double clickable simple inline editing function, I have the css, ajax etc worked out fine (not shown). The problem is when I have edited selected text it changes fine but also changes all the other text on the page to the newly inputted text. Does anybody have any suggestions as to why it would deb doing this and a possible fix?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.editable = function() {
        $('#id').val($(this).attr('id'));
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var textBlock = $(this);
        var textBox = $('<input type="text"/>');
        textBox.hide().insertAfter(textBlock).val(textBlock.html());
        textBlock.dblclick(function() {
            toggleVisiblity(true);
        });

        textBox.blur(function() {
            toggleVisiblity(false);
        });

        toggleVisiblity = function(editMode) {
            if (editMode == true) {
                textBlock.hide();
                textBox.show().focus();
                textBox[0].value = textBox[0].value;
            }
            else {
                textBlock.show();
                textBox.hide();
                textBlock.html(textBox.val());
            }
        };
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    var $edit = $('.edit').editable('#id');
});
```

```html
<p class="edit">Test text 1</p>
<p class="edit">Test text 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal is, but html offers an attribute called "contenteditable" that already allows inline editing.  Please see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Answer (score 0):

The operation has to be performed on the current element that is being *dblclicked*.  Have modified your code to work accordingly.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqnwusph/)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.editable = function() {
        $('#id').val($(this).attr('id'));
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var textBlock;
        var textBox = $('<input type="text"/>');

        $(this).dblclick(function() {            
            textBlock = $(this);
            $(this).hide();
            textBox.hide().insertAfter(textBlock).val(textBlock.html());
            textBox.show().focus();
            textBox[0].value = textBox[0].value;
        });

        textBox.blur(function() {
             textBlock.show();
                textBox.hide();
                textBlock.html(textBox.val());
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Monie your suggestion works perfectly and acicali I have tried yours and it works great although I am now having a new problem you both might be able to help with. As I have "resizable" as a class on the input when the changed text in the input is saved through ajax it also adds "<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;">" and I can't work out how to get rid of it other than str_replace in the php post. Any ideas and thanks again for your original suggestions.